# Where do firefox store the default certificates?

Tags: firefox

Their is a "cert8.db" in the user folder which influence the current certificates, but that file can be deleted and will reappear and restore to default when run firefox next time.

So where is the default certificates store, it must in the program folder, but I even unzip the omni.ja and cannot find any.

My question is neither duplicate of "[Where does Firefox store cerificates and how to delete one?](https://superuser.com/questions/136535)", nor solved by that, I already know there's a cert8.db in the user profile folder, but I want to know the **default** file location, I can delete the cert8.db but it will reappear with all factory certificates still present, so there must be another file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does Firefox store cerificates and how to delete one?](http://superuser.com/questions/136535/where-does-firefox-store-cerificates-and-how-to-delete-one)

Comment: The first answer of the proposed duplicate  describes how to find it.  It isn't clear that there is a different answer.  If it reappears after deletion, perhaps you need to ask a different question--solving that issue, which may not relate to the certificate location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the various files in my Firefox installation folder (c:\program files\mozilla firefox), I find the file "nssckbi.dll", which contains the description "NSS Builtin Trusted Root CAs". So, the certificate data appears to be compiled into the Firefox executables. I think "NSS" stands for Network Security Service.